# how to remove unwanted values from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I got the below o/p

```
["1-3","2-3","1-4","2-4"]
```

in that how can i remove 1-, 2-, 1-, 2-

i want o/p like this

```
["3","3","4","4"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one..

```
<?php 
$input= array('1-3','2-3','1-4','2-4');
$newArr = array();
foreach($input as $key =>$val)
{
    $a = explode('-',$val);
    $newArr[]= $a[1];
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArr);
?>
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 4
)
```

Comment: Thank U dear @ Barnala

Answer (score 3):

Just walk every element in the array and explode it:

```
$arr = ["1-3","2-3","1-4","2-4"];

array_walk($arr, function(&$val){
    $val = explode("-",$val)[1];
});

var_dump($arr);

//array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(1) "4" [3]=> string(1) "4" }
```

Comment: sorry array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(1) "4" [3]=> string(1) "4" }

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you want @KarnaGowtham ?

Comment: i want o/p like this "["3","3","4","4"]"

Comment: That is exactly the outcome of what I wrote. You can't have array values without keys.

Comment: instead of `var_dump` use `print_r`. var_dump shows you the "hidden" keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the dash it the split between the two strings (or number) then you'd need some regex

```
/[^-]+$/
```

This would return the value after the - dash
This would cover you for more than 1 digit should you need it.